Filter an array of objects based on multiple categories
The data looks like:
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    company: "Photosnap",
    logo: "./images/photosnap.svg",
    new: true,
    featured: true,
    position: "Senior Frontend Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Senior",
    postedAt: "1d ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "USA Only",
    languages: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    tools: [],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Manage",
    logo: "./images/manage.svg",
    new: true,
    featured: true,
    position: "Fullstack Developer",
    role: "Fullstack",
    level: "Midweight",
    postedAt: "1d ago",
    contract: "Part Time",
    location: "Remote",
    languages: ["Python, Javascript"],
    tools: ["React"],
  },
  // so on ...
]

I have to filter the data based on the following filter array:
const filter = ["HTML","CSS"]

I would have to display the item that consists of both "HTML" and "CSS", and in this case it would be just the first item in the data.
What would the optimal way to achieve so?

you can check if every element in filter is included in languages
const filteredData = data.filter(job =>
  filter.every(f => job.languages.includes(f))
);


const filter = ["HTML", "CSS"];

//This will create a new Array where condition returns true
const filteredData = data.filter(item => 
  filter.every(language => item.languages.includes(language))
);

//Log the new array
console.log(filteredData );


  const filterLanguages = ["HTML", "CSS"];

  const filteredData = data.filter(job => 
  // Check if all languages in filterLanguages are included in job.languages (array)
  // If so, return true, otherwise return false
 // So false cases will be filtered out
   filterLanguages.every(language => job.languages.includes(language))
   );

// Output the filtered data
console.log(filteredData);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide an additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
